# How to create a ghost environment?

Tags: images, installation

I want to create a ghost or image of a fresh Windows XP development environment with all the various bits of software installed and ready to go, so that when the OS gets clogged or the main disk fails I can simply install the ghost rather than having to run through the entire install and setup process all over again.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Cheers.

Comment: With the exception of total disk failures, have you considered virtualization?  When you have a 'clogged up' making a new one from your virtual hard drive is far faster than restoring from a ghost image or backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**RADIFIED - Guide to Norton
>   Ghost**](http://ghost.radified.com/) presents what many
>   consider the **ultimate back-up
>   strategy**. It is based on features
>   found in Ghost, a hard drive
>   imaging/cloning software program
>   developed by Symantec. Altho designed
>   around Ghost (considered the most
>   reliable application of its kind), the
>   strategies presented here (such as
>   performing a test-restore, to ensure
>   your back-up image will work when you
>   really need it) can be applied to
>   any disk cloning program. After
>   nearly 9 years on the 'Net - and
>   countless updates - it is still the
>   site's most requested Windows
>   tutorial. Users of Ghost from all
>   over the world contribute regularly to
>   the insights it contains, which might
>   be why its popularity continues to
>   grow. When you realize how much time &
>   misery Ghost's supernatural disaster
>   recovery features can save you.

This guide of course is focused the **real** Ghost software.

[image]

Not to be confused with their consumer product, which is also branded Ghost but in fact is based on PowerQuest Drive Image.

the different editions can be identified by their version: anything up to version 8 & version 11 (aka Ghost Solution Suite) is the 'real deal' (versions prior to 8 are not supported in 32bit environments), versions 9, 10, 12, 13 and 14 are not, entirely different ballgame altogether.

[Ghost @ Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_%28software%29#Ghost_Solution_Suite_2.0_.28Ghost_11.0.29)

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Paragon Backup & Recovery 2011 (Advanced) Free Edition](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/br-free/):

[image: Paragon Backup & Recovery 2011 (Advanced) Free Edition]